# Is it possible to restrict a program from reading anything outside what they need?

Tags: security

I understand that running programs as a non-root user is done in order to restrict the programs from writing system files, which prevents malware from compromising the system security.

But in most cases those programs are still able to **read** those system files even though they cannot write them (ex. `/etc/fstab`) which leaves the system vulnerable to wide range of spyware.

So, is it possible to restrict programs in a more draconian way so that they would not be able to access anything outside a defined environment? For example, I could allow `firefox` to use `~/.mozilla`, `~/.cache/mozilla` and `~/Downloads`, but `firefox` will never be able to read anything from `/etc` or such.

Is there such a feature in Linux?

Comment: "which leaves the system vulnerable to wide range of spyware." No it does not. And in case of browsers have a search for the word "sandbox".

Comment: Take a look at the apparmor firefox (or other browser) profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method to restrict access on Ubuntu is with apparmor.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor

Firefox comes with an apparmor profile for Firefox which has been specifically developed with security in mind.

as pointed out by Rinzwind , ro access is not necessarily a security problem.

Large programs such as firefox is not the best of examples as firefox has rather broad capabilities from network access to hardware access.

As you can see, the firefox apparmor profile is quite large. You can certainly modify the apparmor profile to your specific needs / concerns if you so desire. Just be sure to save a copy of the original profile so you can restore it if you break firefox functionality.

Other browsers, such as chromium, run is a sandbox.

If you are particularly interested in security, you can run Fedora with selinux and run applications in a selinux sandbox.

apparmor profiles are available here

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/AppArmorProfiles

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is: it is called the `chroot` environment (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot).

Comment: Actually the method is to use apparmor.